# How to apply my own filter on an image in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have two filter, one for x dimension and other for y dimension. Now I want to apply it on an
image which is a 2D matrix. How to do it?
Suppose if I have a 5*5 image and 3*1 filter for columns and 1*3 filter for rows. I can do it using loop but I want to ask if there is any function in opencv that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, if you have the separate filter, you could use *[sepFilter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20sepFilter2D%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernelX,%20InputArray%20kernelY,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType%29)*.
Example:

```
sepFilter2D(source5x5img, dst, deepth, filterX, filterY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV's `filter2D`-function (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d).
Just apply your kernel matrix as 4th parameter of the function.
Hope it helps!